# How to get logs of codepipeline using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

So when I trigger a codepipeline using the below command:

```
aws codepipeline start-pipeline-execution --name MyFirstPipeline
```

I only get an asynchronous response

```
{
    "pipelineExecutionId": "c53dbd42-This-Is-An-Example"
}
```

Now how do I stream the logs of build and deploy stages?

P.S I can see the logs in cloud watch but how can I get that logs using AWS cli?

Comment: Which logs? Do you have any example/screenshot?

Comment: I mean codedeploy and codebuild logs via AWS cli

Comment: They will be in cloudwatch.

Comment: yeah but I am triggering using CLI. How Can I see that logs in terminal using AWS CLI?

Comment: You can't. You have to query CloudWatch independently.

Comment: You can access codebuild and codedeploy logs from CLI using `aws logs` command. An example to get codebuild logs is to first get the log group `aws logs describe-log-groups --query 'logGroups[?contains(logGroupName, `codebuild`)]'`, then get the log-streams using `aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name --log-stream-name` and finally you call `aws logs get-log-events` with the log-group-name and log-stream-name that you got from previous 2 commands